# No Oracle Developer Tools and Datasources

Tags: visual-studio, database-connection

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and installed Oracle Developer Tools 12.1.0.1.0.

When I try to add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model, Oracle database isn't listed in the list of available connections.

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio is not listed in the Visual Studio About dialog. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I thought I needed 64 bit Oracle, but as Visual Studio is always 32 bit, I had to install 32 bit Oracle, and it worked.